# No hits with from a Zend Search MultiTerm Query? (There should be 3)

Tags: php, symfony, zend-search-lucene

I have a search form with a name, club, natranking, doublesranking and club field. I have selected a club from the selectbox, left the name field blank and clicked 'Search'. The result has no hits. There should be 3 as there are 3 records in the database that are part of that chosen club. Why is that?

Thx.

Controller class:

```
$search = $this->get('ewz_search.lucene');

// Create query
$terms = array(new Term($form->getData()->getName(), 'name'),
    new Term($form->getData()->getClub(), 'club'),
    new Term($form->getData()->getNatRanking(), 'natranking'),
    new Term($form->getData()->getNatDoublesRanking(), 'doublesranking')
);
$signs = array(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE);
$query = new MultiTerm($terms, $signs);

// Get results 
$results = $search->find($query);

// Echo prints: "+name: +club:A.R.A. LA GANTOISE +natranking: +doublesranking:"
echo $query;

// This returns 0
die("debug: " . count($results);
```

//EDIT

This works (gives me 3 results):

```
$manual_query = "+name: +club:A.R.A. LA GANTOISE +natranking: +doublesranking:";
```

Comment: What does your Lucene index look like? How did you index the data there? You can use a tool like Luke to look at the index, is the data actually indexed as you thought?

Comment: I will check how the Lucene index looks like when I'm home tonight. But I think it's ok as the manual query does work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I casted the Multiterm object to a string and now it works. 
That's strange as the example in the docs clearly show that it should work without casting it to a string:

Examle from docs (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.query-api.html#zend.search.lucene.queries.multiterm-query)

```
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();

$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('word1'), true);
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('word2', 'author'),
            null);
$query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('word3'), false);

$hits  = $index->find($query);
```

Comment: so you lost 50 repo then i suppose http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty

Comment: Well who should I give the bounty to then? :)